# Is it possible to apply the kernel trick to Naive Bayes algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian-networks

I would like to improve something about naive bayes algorithm for my computer science thesis, i was reading about the kernel trick and how it can improve SVMs and other machine learning algorithms. Is this all ready done?. Any other aproach to improve naive bayes algorithm or another classfier?

Answer (score 5):

Naive Bayes doesn't involve any inner products, and the kernel trick is used to replace inner product operations. So no, you can't kernelize Naive Bayes.

You could run Naive Bayes on an explicitly formed feature space that approximates some kernel, but the interpretation wouldn't really make any sense.

Comment: Thank you by your answer by the way... im desperate since i have no thesis theme... any idea of what kind of problem attack using kernel machines?

Comment: I assume this is a BS level thesis, so what would be valid would depend on what level of work your department wants. It would be best to ask your potential thesis advisors or someone in the department who works in ML.

Comment: yes this is a BS thesis, but nobody in my department want to give me ideas and my potential thesis advisors let me alone. Any cool idea for a thesis?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel trick is already used pretty much anywhere where it applies - because it's quite obvious where to plug it into algorithms: scalar products and similarity measurements.

Naive bayes has already been improved a million times. You will have to read a *lot* of literature.

You'll have to come up with a *much more specific idea*, sorry. The low hanging fruit have all been eaten.

Answer (score -2):

In some sense the NB algorithm is already itself something like a kernel. You set up its parameters and it gives you distances between points, namely the probability that the two points belong to the same class. So the question is just the opposite. How could you use the NB algorithm as a kernel, say, in a K-NN classifier ?

Comment: If you downvote it, please explain why. I think people who downvoted it do not get the point of the answer, sorry .... :)

Comment: Its probably because your explanation is wrong. NB is not like a mercer kernel in any real way. It doesn't even give good probabilities, let alone trying to use it the measurer the similarity between points (which it does not do).

Comment: Why is it wrong? You can define a distance from NB , which defines a scalar pruduct. How good the pobabilities are has nothing to do whether NB conceptually can be interpredet as a kernel or not. Science is about thinking outside of the box! Try it for a change :)

Comment: A) Defining a distance isn't equivalent to defining a scalar product.
B) A scalar product is not equivalent to a mercer kernel
C) I doubt you could define a _valid_ *distance metric* with naive bays.
D) I already told you why your wrong - NB is not a like a kernel. It has none of the properties of a kernel. You are making the positive statement, the burden of proof is on you. Prove it is a mercer kernel and I will apologize and accept you are correct.
E) Science is more about provable results and reproducibility. Attacking my character in a snarky way does neither.

Comment: From a distance you can define a scalar product, ever heard of the law of cosines? You should have paid more attention in high school my friend :)

Comment: Only if it is a valid distance metric, any arbitrary distance function does not imply a valid scalar product. You should have paid attention to what I emphasized. Unless you plan on addressing what I've actually said - I'll stop here.

Comment: I don't know if you can define one... but if you you can then all is good. All I meant with the answer that conceptually the NB is closer to being a kernel itself than something on which a kernel should be used. In other words, it does not make sense to use a kernel on something which is already itself something like a kernel (if the distances can be defined in a proper way). What I meant is exactly that... it would be interesting research project to see how and if one can turn the NB into a kernel. Note I did not say it is a kernel, I said it is conceptually something **like** a kernel.